# I am trying to start a "hedge fund," and by that, I really just mean I have a very specific and somewhat simple investment thesis that I want to

Tags: hedging

basically, I have a few stocks in mind that I want to sell short, so it will likely be just me, possibly one or two other people working very part-time, and that's about it. In any event, I will need to raise money. So, my question is, should I start--and I hate how arrogant this sounds--a hedge fund, a cta or cpo? Also, based on your answers, can you tell me how to get started? Any help is greatly appreciated. Again, the whole idea is just to legally form a very, very basic "company" that would allow me to beg for money, finalize the stocks I wanna short from my shortlist, pun fully intended, and then simply short them. Basically, I just need to know which legal hoops I need to jump through and how to jump through them in order to implement a simple but attractive investment thesis.

Comment: Good luck. I hope you have hundreds of millions of liquid cash.

Answer (score 4):

Kudos for wanting to start your own business.  Now let's talk reality.

Unless you already have some kind of substantial track record of successful investing to show potential investors, what you want to do will never happen, and that's just giving you the honest truth.

There are **extensive** regulatory requirements for starting any kind of public investment vehicle, and meeting them costs *money*.  You can be your own hedge fund with your own money and avoid all of this if you like.  Keep in mind that a "hedge fund" is little more than someone who is contrarian to the market and puts their money where their mouth is.  (I know, some of you will argue this is simplistic, and you'd be right, but I'm deliberately avoiding complexity for the moment)

The simple truth is that nobody is going to just give you their money to invest unless, for starters, you can show that you're any good at it (and for the sake of it we'll assume you've had success in the markets), and (perhaps most importantly) you have "skin in the game", meaning you have a substantial investment of your own in the fund too.

You might have a chance at creating something ***if*** you can show that whatever your hedge fund proposes to invest in isn't already overrun by other hedge funds.  At the moment, there are more mutual and hedge funds out there than there are securities for them to invest in, so they're basically all fighting over the same pie.  You must have some fairly unique opportunity or approach that nobody else has or has even considered in order to begin attracting money to a new fund these days.  And that's not easy, trust me.

There is no short or easy path to what you want to do, and perhaps if you want to toy around with it a bit, find some friends who are willing to invest based on your advice and/or picks.  If you develop a track record of success then perhaps you could more seriously consider doing what you propose, and in the meanwhile you can look into the requirements for laying the foundations toward your goal.

I hope you don't find my answer cruel, because it isn't meant to be.  I am all about encouraging people to succeed, but it has to start with a realistic expectation.  You have a great thought, but there's a wide gulf from concept to market and no quick or simple way to bridge it.

Here's a link to a web video on how to start your own hedge fund, if you want to look into it more deeply:

[How To Legally Start A Hedge Fund (From the Investopedia website)](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/financial-theory/11/how-to-legally-form-a-hedge-fund.asp)

Good luck!

Comment: The part about doing something that a thousand other hedge funds aren't doing is really the key part: there aren't. So, suffice it to say, I'm optimistic (relatively speaking, of course) about being able to raise money if I can get in front of people with money because my investment thesis is great along a number of dimensions: simple, unique, clever, with an awesome risk/reward ratio. The part I'm worried about is jumping through the legal hoops and being granted an opportunity to beg in the first place. Also, never forget Martin Shkreli: he has the distinction of blowing up 2 funds before 30

Comment: Check my answer for a revision and a link to a video on the subject.  Maybe it'll help you along.

Comment: It's amazing there's a "How to! ... start a hedge fund!" video!  :O

Comment: I'm sure if you spend any time at all looking around, there's a video on "How To Make a 'How-To' Video". (chuckle)